# アルファベットの i の点を無くした上でアクセント記号を付けたい

Tags: latex

LaTeXで単に `\acute{i}` と書くと i の点の上にアクセント記号が乗ってしまいます。

Unicode で言うところの "Latin Small Letter I with acute" `í` を出したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通常の地の文では`\'i`で出力されます．

Comment: +1: 上手く動きました。`\acute` と `\'` って等価じゃなかったのですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

`\i` が "dot-less i" になります。したがって `\acute{\i}` と書くと上手くいきました。数式中では `\acute{\imath}` というのも用意されています。

なお j についても同様に `\j`、`\jmath` が用意されています。